# Create invoice again which was deleted programmatically

Tags: invoice, programmatically, create-invoice

I had deleted an invoice programmatically by using the following code:

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load(97);
$invoice->delete();
```

Now I need Invoice Button to invoice again. I have done lot of Google but didn't got success.

Please Help Me

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this case is that the order's state needs to be reset.

I had a similar issue where the invoice was deleted, but I could not create a new invoice.

I used this code on a `test.php` page to successfully reset the order's status manually. It does delete all invoices in the process just in case there is anything left over.

```
$order_id = 97;
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadbyIncrementId($order_id);
$invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
    $invoice->delete();
}
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true)->save();
```

Comment: use loadbyIncrementId if $order_id is something like '10000111' , if not just 'load'